# Obtaining a reference to a NotesView with NotesDatabase.Views(x) can be surprisingly slow

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In VB6, I'm supporting code that loops through all the views in a Lotus Notes database thusly:

```
    For lngdomViewidx = LBound(domDatabase.Views) To UBound(domDatabase.Views)
         Set domView = domDatabase.Views(lngdomViewidx) ' note: this line right here is slow to execute
```

The amount of time it takes to retrieve a reference to the view by index with this method seems proportional to the number of documents in the view. This bit of code is just looping through the Notes database to build a list of all the view names. On really large databases this can take several minutes. Is there a faster way to get this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a very efficient way, no.

Use something like the code below instead. It is Lotusscript, but it should be pretty much the same in VB. I haven't tested it, just copied it from a production database and modified it to look for views instead for forms like in my original...

```
Dim ncol As NotesNoteCollection
Set ncol = db.CreateNoteCollection(True)    
Call ncol.SelectAllNotes(False)
ncol.SelectViews = True
Call ncol.BuildCollection
noteID = ncol.GetFirstNoteId
For i = 1 To ncol.Count
    Set doc = targetdb.GetDocumentByID(noteID)
    MsgBox "view = " + doc.GetItemValue("$Title")(0)
    noteID = ncol.GetNextNoteId(noteID)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Karl-Henry is absolutely right: The NotesNoteCollection is really the fastest way to loop through all views. 
But you can speed up your code significantly by just changing the loop.
Instead of opening each view using its index, you coud, do something like:

```
Forall view in db.Views
  'Do whatever you want
End Forall
```

Accessing elements in a collection in Lotus Notes using the index means, that it always has to count from the beginning, while using a forall- loop directly accesses the next element...

Comment: db.Views is an array of objects, not a collection of objects.  Array elements are accessed directly by multiplying the index and element size to find the offset, so there is no need to count from the beginning.   However I do agree that the loop would be optimized a bit by using a forall because those calls to LBound(domDatabase.Views) To UBound(domDatabase.Views) on every iteration are going to be costly.  Another way to get a similar optimization would just be to assign domDatabase.Views to a variant before the loop and referencing LBound and UBound of the variant in the for statement.

Comment: (I also agree that Karl-Henry's suggestion of NotesNoteCollection is the right way to go.)

Comment: The reason that the calls are costly is because resolving properties of objects is costly.  Therefore it's even better IMHO to assign the LBound and UBound to integer variables and reference THOSE in your for loop.  A variant is just going to be a reference to the object anyway, so you're not really avoiding accessing the object.  Unless Notes takes all of these variations and treats them internally the same way that forall works.  :)

Comment: Running the Forall loop is significantly faster than the indexed array for-loop. Its not the ubounds/lbounds, its fetching the entire view objects array for all views on each iteration of the For loop that costs. The forall effectively loads the array once into ram and then calculates array position as Richard suggests. In my tests, the forall runs over 500 times quicker than the for-loop. The phrase 'optimised a bit' is completely misleading and inaccurate!